How to update amount using Elements in stripe & react?
I am using the PaymentElement to accept payments. The problem is after a clientSecret is generated, and the amount is updated on my website it doesn't reflect the update amount. The only way it will reflect if the page is reloaded.
Is there anyway where i can have the amount updated? Below is my code. Any help would be really appreciated. Below is my code
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import CheckoutForm from '../../components/CheckoutForm'; // Adjust the path as needed
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export default function CheckoutPage() {
    const storeInfo = useSelector((state) => state.storeInfo);
    const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);

    const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(null);
    const params = useParams();
    const storeId = params.store_id;

    const grandTotal = useSelector((state) => state.cart.grandTotal); // Assuming it's in the cart slice

    useEffect(() => {
        const grandTotalInCents = Math.round(grandTotal * 100);

        const fetchClientSecret = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('/api/checkout/create-payment-intent', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        amount: grandTotalInCents, // Dummy amount in cents
                        name: 'Dummy User', // Dummy name
                        email : "test@gmail.com"
                    }),
                });

                const data = await response.json();



                if (data.clientSecret) {
                    setClientSecret(data.clientSecret);
                } else {
                    console.error('Failed to retrieve client secret:', data);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching client secret:', error);
            }
        };

        fetchClientSecret();
    }, [grandTotal]); // Dependency array ensures this runs when grandTotal changes



    return (
        <div className="container mt-5">
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-end mb-3"></div>
            {stripePromise && clientSecret && (
                <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={{ clientSecret }}>
                    <CheckoutForm clientSecrett={clientSecret} />
                </Elements>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}


You should just call elements.fetchUpdates() to reflect the updates on the existing Payment Element.
